Data sorting issue on laravel
I'm facing an issue with returning data with sorting on Laravel.
I would like to sort the data by the created date and order it by the Job number simultaneously.
I have tried setting this up in the SQL, but the result is not what I want.
The data is as follows:



taskid
Createtime
JobNo




101337
3/7/2024  12:21:21 PM
23120099AN


101338
3/7/2024  12:25:47 PM
23120099AN


101353
3/7/2024  4:58:48 PM
23110245IR


101363
3/7/2024  8:25:57 PM
23120095AN


101364
3/7/2024  8:29:51 PM
23110245IR


101365
3/7/2024  8:30:22 PM
23110245IR


101369
4/7/2024  12:46:25 AM
23120777AN


101371
4/7/2024  12:47:21 AM
23120777AN


101372
4/7/2024  12:47:59 AM
23120099AN


101373
4/7/2024  12:49:06 AM
23120099AN



And the result I want is:



taskid
Createtime
JobNo




101337
3/7/2024  12:21:21 PM
23120099AN


101338
3/7/2024  12:25:47 PM
23120099AN


101372
4/7/2024  12:47:59 AM
23120099AN


101373
4/7/2024  12:49:06 AM
23120099AN


101353
3/7/2024  4:58:48 PM
23110245IR


101364
3/7/2024  8:29:51 PM
23110245IR


101365
3/7/2024  8:30:22 PM
23110245IR


101363
3/7/2024  8:25:57 PM
23120095AN


101369
4/7/2024  12:46:25 AM
23120777AN


101371
4/7/2024  12:47:21 AM
23120777AN



Could you please help me understand how I can achieve the desired sorting, where the data is first ordered by the Createtime (ASC) and sorting by the JobNo as same time?

What have you tried ? can you share some code so we dont have to guess how you are getting the data from database (even a simplified version is ok).

Please show your code/sql query. At a guess, you need to sort by JobNo first, then Createtime.

You must first order on JobNo and then order on Createtime.
So in Laravel syntax:
->orderByDesc('JobNo')->orderByDesc('Createtime');
Normally laravel is using timestamps() that will automatically create columns: created_at and updated_at.
Don't forget to cast Createtime to be a datetime format in the model.

you dont have to cast to datetime to be able to sort by date. also it would not help to sort it by date in the database.

Thank you for your reply,but this can’t order by the create at, we hope can base first in first out to display the jobno(group by same jobno)

@thomaslam add you code to your question instead on answering comments.
